# Find Source/Destination based on a single column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the following data

```
ID  Source     Destination  PFID
1   Loc X      Loc Y        1
2   Loc Y      Loc Z        1
3   Delhi      Kolkata      3
4   Kolkata    Dhaka        3
```

The above table stores the data of connecting flights between different cities. I want a result in the following format -

```
Source     Destination  PFID
Loc X      Loc Z        1
Delhi      Dhanka       3
```

Please advise on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Just selfJOIN  the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `group by` clause with conditional aggregation

```
select min(case when pfid = id then Source end) [Source], 
       max(case when pfid <> id then Destination end) [Destination], PFID 
from table
group by PFID
```

**Edit :**

You could also directly fetch the source and destination station by using `first_value()` and `last_value()` function

```
select distinct first_value(Source) over (partition by PFID order by PFID) , last_value(Destination) over (partition by PFID order by PFID), PFID 
from table
order by PFID
```

Note : The above is tested based on data provided in `Q`

Comment: I think `max(case when pfid <> id then Destination end)` isn't right if you have more than 2 items in a path.

Comment: @Leran2002 I have modified it to use max(ID) to ensure it finds the last item in the path

Comment: @Nitesh - I added one more variant into my answer. It's a symbiosis from two solutions.

Comment: @Leran2002 first_value() works only with 2016 and above :)

Comment: @Nitesh - I tested it on SQLServer 2014 and it works. `FIRST_VALUE` is starting with 2012 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
SELECT q.PFID,p1.Source,p2.Destination
FROM
  (
    SELECT PFID,MIN(ID) SourceID,MAX(ID) DestinationID
    FROM [Your Table]
    GROUP BY PFID
  ) q
JOIN [Your Table] p1 ON p1.ID=q.SourceID
JOIN [Your Table] p2 ON p2.ID=q.DestinationID
```

Or you can use window functions `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` if your version of SQLServer supports them

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PFID,
  FIRST_VALUE(Source)OVER(PARTITION BY PFID ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Source,
  LAST_VALUE(Destination)OVER(PARTITION BY PFID ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Destination
FROM [Your Table]
```

If `ID` are inconsistent then you can use a recursive CTE

```
;WITH cte AS(
  -- start point
  SELECT ID,Source,Destination,PFID,1 step
  FROM [Your Table]
  WHERE PFID=ID

  UNION ALL

  -- next point
  SELECT t.ID,c.Source,t.Destination,t.PFID,c.step+1
  FROM [Your Table] t
  JOIN cte c ON t.Source=c.Destination
)
SELECT PFID,Source,Destination
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      PFID,
      Source,
      Destination,
      step,
      MAX(step)OVER(PARTITION BY PFID) LastStep
    FROM cte
  ) q
WHERE step=LastStep
```

It's a symbiosis from two queries which provided Yogesh Sharma and my first query

```
SELECT s.PFID,s.Source,d.Destination
FROM
  (
    SELECT PFID,MIN(CASE WHEN PFID=ID THEN Source END) Source,MAX(ID) DestinationID
    FROM [Your Table]
    GROUP BY PFID
  ) s
JOIN [Your Table] d ON d.ID=s.DestinationID
```

Comment: After a number of INSERTs and DELETEs, and for any other reason, MIN(ID) can be not the first point in a chain and MAX(ID) not the last one.

Comment: You're right but the author said nothing about it. ) I added one more variant with recursive CTE for this case, too.